# How to get AppCenter to run updated Xamarin.UITest scripts from VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.uitest, visual-studio-app-center-test

My tests run in MS AppCenter just fine but I had to update my scripts with a different Username and Password to login. I made the updates in my VS Test.cs file and clicked saved. But every time I run the AppCenter test from Command Prompt my tests execute but end up with a Fail status because it's still using the prior Username and Password which is invalid.  I run it locally in VS and the scripts work fine. How can I fix this?

I tried closing and reopening all applications.  Tried new test runs. Is there a cache issue here? If so how do I clear it?

Answer (score 0):

AppCenter is running with the old build. in my opinion after changing the password script you should build your project then run on the AppCenter

Comment: I've tried this and it's still not using the new username and password.  Do I need to upload a new build to app center maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what my problem was.  I was using the wrong build path to my UITest.  So once I corrected the path in my AppCenter CLI script it began working as expected.